# Divide bottom row to match top row in table - HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm wanting to do some formatting with tables and I can't seem to figure out how to equally divide the bottom row to have the same width as the top row.

I want the top row to be like 240px, and have the bottom row divided into two parts with 120px each.

Below is a image for reference:
[image]

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

All help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**:
[image]
[image]

That is the issue that I'm having with the colspan:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @StardustGogeta, that doesn't work, it turns it into the top being 100% and the bottom turning 50% but filling in the whole space

Comment: `colspan` anyone?

Comment: @Sema You're right, I forgot how that worked. Paulie_D's solution is definitely the best way to do it.

Comment: colspan worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Use colspan attribute in the first tag and set the width of table in CSS. Here is a JSFiddle for reference. https://jsfiddle.net/6dvnafrm/

```
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @an_own, I've updated the post with a new problem

Comment: The photos are not loading for me can you describe the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this:

```css
 th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }   
 td{
 width:240px;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<table>      
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
</table> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amaresh S M, I've updated the post with a new problem

Answer (score 0):

Setting colspan="2" to the top td fixed it.

```
<tr colspan="2" class="footbar">
    <td colspan="2"><td>
</tr>
```